# Typescript: How to use two interfaces in a partial OR

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface.

```
interface TEMP {
  type: object;
}

interface NEW_TEMP {
  newType: Array<object>
}

export type = TEMP_PAYLOAD = Partial<TEMP | NEW_TEMP>

const function = (temp: TEMP_PAYLOAD) => {
  console.log(temp.newType) // -> property "newType" is not exist on type 'Partial<TEMP> | Partial<NEW_TEMP>' property "Type" is not exists on type 'Partial<NEW_TEMP>'
}
```

And I want to specify that one payload belongs to either interface.

I used a combination of Partial and OR as follows but it doesn't work as I want.

How can i do this?

Comment: Why two interface when the only difference is one is an array of objects, unless you can be more specific about the objects beings used.

Comment: do you want `TEMP_PAYLOAD` to be `{ type?: object, newType?: Array<object> }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
type TEMP_PAYLOAD =
  | (Partial<TEMP> & { tag: 1 })
  | (Partial<NEW_TEMP> & { tag: 2 });

let a: TEMP_PAYLOAD = 1 as any;
if (a.tag == 1) {
  a.type
}
```

1. make a compiler-aware tag to distinguish the Union type
2. narrow the union type to a specific one